# JS - Показать подменю при клике на стрелочку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код меню для разрешения `min-width:960`, которое при наведении раскрывается. Как мне сделать, чтобы оно точно также раскрывалось, только по клику на `fa-angle-down` для разрешения  `max-width:960` и чтобы последнее подменю раскрывалось справа всегда одинаково, как на картинке?
 Если я ставлю для класса `.item position:relative`, то высота подменю берется от `item`, а не от всего блока.

[image: Пример как должно быть]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('body').on('click','.fa-angle-down', toggleParent); 
  function toggleParent() { 
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
  $(this) 
    .parents('.item.parent')
    .toggleClass('active');
    $(this) 
    .siblings('.sub-menu') 
    .toggleClass('open'); 
  } 


});
```

```css
 .menuIndex>.item.parent {
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item>a {
        padding: 15px 15px;
        float: left;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        display: table;
    }
  .menuIndex .item .sub-menu .item {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 2.3em;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: initial;
  }
  .menuIndex .item .sub-menu .item a {
    color: #707070;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block;
  }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent a:hover,.menuIndex>.item.parent a:focus,header .menu .menuIndex>.item.parent a.active {
        background-color: #f0f5f8;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent>a{
        position: relative;
        padding: 4px 0 9px 65px !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #166816;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        outline: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 260px;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent>a:hover{
        background-color: #166816 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent>a:after{
        content: "\f0c9";
        font-family: 'icons' !important;
        padding-left: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent>.fa-angle-down{
        right: 60px;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 9999;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item .fa-angle-down{
        display: block;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent>.fa-angle-down.active{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        text-align: right;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .menuIndex>.item.parent>.sub-menu{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        outline: none;
        outline-width: 0px;
        z-index: 999;
        background: #fff;    
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item{
        display: block;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 2.3em;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>a{
        color: #707070;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: initial;
        padding: 0;
        padding: 0 20px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        background: transparent;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.sub-menu>.item a:after,.menuIndex .item:hover .sub-menu .sub-menu .item a:before{
        ontent: "";
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item.parent>.sub-menu{
        display: none;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item>.sub-menu{
        display: none;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item:hover>a{
        border: 1px solid #166816;
        color: #000;
    }  
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 7px #868484;
        box-shadow: 3px 2px 7px #868484;
        background: #fff;
    }  
   .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 40px 0 20px;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 2.9em;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: initial;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #707070;
    }
    .menuIndex>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>.item.parent:hover>.sub-menu>a:hover{
        background-color: #f0f5f8;
        color: @black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/094f305d52.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="menuIndex">
            <div class="item parent">
              <a href="" class="noLink">Каталог</a>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div class="item parent">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <nav class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="">Мука</a>
                        <a href="">Крупы</a>
                        <a href="">Сахар</a>
                        <a href="">Греча</a>
                      </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="item parent">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <nav class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="">Мука</a>
                        <a href="">Крупы</a>
                        <a href="">Сахар</a>
                        <a href="">Греча</a>
                      </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="">Молочные продукты</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Comment: Не ставьте relative у item, установите его для всего menu.

Comment: а стрелки как сделать? если у item не ставить релативе то стрелки все будут вверху

Comment: Оберните ссылку и иконку еще в один div и уже его делайте relative

Comment: я не могу обернуть, получиться что у каждой ссылки вне зависимости есть подменю или нет будет срелочка

Comment: данное меню делаю для modx revo и не получается вывод если обернуть ссылку и стрелку в div